# JavaScript push not working as expected, but a console log right before the push method shows exactly what I was expecting

Tags: javascript

When I run the following code, the console logs give me exactly what I want, but the end array of objects doesn't which I really don't understand..

```js
function pickWinners(numbers) {  
    const winnerArr = [];
    const winnerObj = {};
    for(let i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++) {
        if(numbers[i] % 2 != 0 && i % 2 != 0) {
            winnerObj.seat = i;
            winnerObj.ticketCost = numbers[i];
            console.log(winnerObj);
            winnerArr.push(winnerObj);
        }
    }
    return winnerArr;
}

pickWinners([6, 7, 12, 49])
```

The console log gives me (as expected):

```js
Object { seat: 1, ticketCost: 7 }   
Object { seat: 3, ticketCost: 49 }
```

But the returned array is:

```
0: Object { seat: 3, ticketCost: 49 }  
1: Object { seat: 3, ticketCost: 49 }
```

Could someone please explain what is going on? Especially when the console log is executed just before the push.

Thanks in advance!

I was expecting the returned array to be the same result as what was printed with the console log

Comment: You're pushing the same object over and over again. You'll have to re-initialize `winnerObj` **inside** the loop.

Comment: place the `const winnerObj = {};` inside your loop, otherwise it's just the same instance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to define your `winnerObj` inside your `for` loop so it is block-scoped. This causes a new `winnerObj` to be created each time. The code you currently have is using the same `winnerObj` for each instance. And when you change `winnerObj`, it changes the instances that are already in the array, too.

If you still don't understand, try reading this: https://dmitripavlutin.com/value-vs-reference-javascript/

```js
function pickWinners(numbers) {
  const winnerArr = [];
  for(let i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++) {
    const winnerObj = {};
    if(numbers[i] % 2 != 0 && i % 2 != 0) {
      winnerObj.seat = i;
      winnerObj.ticketCost = numbers[i];
      console.log(winnerObj);
      winnerArr.push(winnerObj);
    }
  }
  return winnerArr;
}

console.log("overall:", pickWinners([6, 7, 12, 49]))
```